# Misleading review audit

Tags: discussion, review, review-audits, self-answer, disputed-review-audits

I just failed [this answer audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/4348847), and I found out that it was a user posting an answer to their own question. The answer showed the code for the progress that they had made so far (the problem had not been fixed). After the audit failed, it was obvious that the answer should have been an edit to the question that the OP posted.

Normally, I would appreciate the information that a review audit gives to me (I've had one or two so far).

However, I'd like to point out that with no comments and no username, it was downright **impossible** to know that this answer should have been an edit to the question. I think this audit was not a fair way to judge my work as a reviewer.

To me, the answer seemed like it was okay. I clicked "Looks Good", which, apparently, was wrong.

I would appreciate any insight into this audit and how I may be of better assistance reviewing in the future. As I stated earlier, I have only failed one or two audits (not recently) and I am unable to review for two days.

Comment: I agree. Self-answers shouldn't be used for audits. Especially for new users, as they tend to post additional information as answers. In these cases, I feel it's just not possible to judge whether something is really an answer or not.

Comment: For some edits I have reviewed I have viewed the whole Q&A to review the edit in context. The question's title, in the edit window, links to the question.

Comment: You can tell it is a self answer because of the blue background on the username section BTW.